# Azure Log Analytics and custom logs with schema?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm working with Azure log analytics and for example `SigninLogs` and a customer want to have some fields with anonymous values like `userPrincipalaName`. I think we have no possibility to do that in the same table, so I want to copy the data from `SigninLogs` to a custom table. But when I do so, I get field names like `Identity_s` for a String field and so on.

So my question is now, is this possible to insert data and submit the schema, so I get the right column names like `Identity`?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api#record-type-and-properties) Azure document, currently Azure Monitor by design automatically adds a suffix to property name based on the property's data type.

[image]

If interested, you may share it (i.e., the requirement of providing users the rights to dynamically provide or update a property name) as a feature request in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics) uservoice or feedback forum and also upvote it and other features that are of interest. In general, Azure feature team would check feasibility of a feature request, triage it, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this document, but I want to know if it is possible to push a schema to stop adding this _postfix.

in the meantime, a microsoft colleague told me, that this is not possible. :-(

Thanks for your answer